# Can't connect to Minecraft Server via Telekom Speedport

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have problems to connect to a certain (Nitrado hosted) Minecraft Server. When I used my FritzBox Router, it worked perfectly. But now I use Telekom Speedport and I got the `[Server Connector #5/ERROR]: Couldn't connect to server io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information` message. I already restarted my Router, Minecraft and my PC without success. I am not sure what else I should do, since other Servers are working perfectly.

Comment: Update: I looked in older logs, and instead of ```server.ip:10400``` my Client now tries to connect to ```server.ip:25565```. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I am sorry... I figured it out: I just changed the Server-ip from`server.ip` to `server.ip:10400`. I am still curious why that happened. If someone knows why, I would be grateful to hear it! :D

Comment: what do you have the port in your server software set to?